# simple function to parse HTML GET request - C and prints line by line

Tags: c

I have written a simple code to process `buffer` array containing http get request. so basically its a firefox request. I dont think it matters

Basically When I print the buffer request without my function it looks like this

```
GET /Khi/next HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5007
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,im
*->here next line executed in C program after above printf;
```

I just check for character `\n` if found it just print the line and set the line to memset 0 so next line is stored for printing. Its in loop.

But I am not getting what is expected. I am getting more line breaks. way more than what actually printed on screen when I just print the entire request

This is my code

problem is in the process function

```
// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 5007

void process(char *buffer,int size,char status)
{
    int i=0;
    int line_len=0;
    char *line=malloc(sizeof(char) *150);
    
    while(i<size)
    {
        if(line_len==148)
        {
            line_len=0;
        }

        if(buffer[i]=='\n')
            {
                printf("line break found\n");
                
                printf("%s",line);
                memset(line,0,sizeof(char) * line_len);
                printf("_____________________________________________\n");
                line_len=0;
            }
        line[line_len]=buffer[i];
        line_len++;
        i++;
    }

}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[500] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    
    
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                                &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    
    
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, (500));
        process(buffer,500,'r');
        buffer[200]='\0';
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
        close(new_socket);

    }   
    return 0;
}
```

And the individual lines are not printing any good either. because the check for `\n` may not be working correctly

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) *150);` why `150`? `if(line_len==148)` why `148`? `buffer[200]='\0';` why `200`? Don't use such numbers at all - calculate them. `process(buffer,500` why `500`? That's invalid - `valread` if `> 0` contains the count of numbers read. It's not `500`. You just increment `while(i<size)`, so if `read()` returns lower then `500`, you are just going to read uninitialized memory.

Comment: You could also consider using the POSIX functions [`fdopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) or [`fmemopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen), and then use `fgets()` to read the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example, how you could implement your process function (declaration slightly changed):

```
int process(const char *buffer, int size)
{
    #define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 4096 //large enough buffer
    char line_buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH]; //either on stack or on heap via malloc
    char *line = line_buffer; //buffer iterator
    char *line_max = line + MAX_LINE_LENGTH; //end of line (literally)

    int i=0;

    while ((i < size) && (line < line_max)) {
        
        //copy characters from buffer into line buffer
        *line = buffer[i];

        //line endings are "\r\n", therefore we test for '\r' (first occurrence)
        if (buffer[i] == '\r') {

            //make null-terminated string
            *line = '\0';
            //reset line
            line = line_buffer;

            //now you have a valid line (null-terminated string)
            //do what needed to be done, e.g. (based on your example)
            printf("line break found\n");
            printf("%s\n", line);
            printf("_____________________________________________\n");

            //skip new line characters
            while ((buffer[i] == '\r') || (buffer[i] == '\n')) ++i;

        } else {

            //increment indices
            ++line;
            ++i;

        }

    }

    //returns the position after the last newline character, 
    return size - (line - line_buffer);
}
```

---

**Test**:

```
int main()
{
    char *str =
    "GET /Khi/next HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: localhost:5007\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0\r\n"
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,im\r\n\r\n";
    
    process(str, strlen(str));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
line break found
GET /Khi/next HTTP/1.1
_____________________________________________
line break found
Host: localhost:5007
_____________________________________________
line break found
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
_____________________________________________
line break found
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,im
_____________________________________________
```